# ServiceStack with IIS

Tags: iis-6, servicestack

I'm trying to publish my website that contains references to servicestack rest APIs.

The Website is fine, but when it tries to access my REST services generated by ServiceStack, it returns 404 errors.

Does anyone know how to publish serviceStack REST services on IIS6?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't get ServiceStack to work in IIS6 with HTTPS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005222/cant-get-servicestack-to-work-in-iis6-with-https)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the instructions on [ServiceStack's Hello World tutorial](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/#custompath):

> Note: due to limitations in IIS 6 - the /custompath must end with
>   .ashx, e.g: path="servicestack.ashx"

The name can be anything, e.g. it can be `api.ashx` if you want.

The limitations of handler mappings in ASP.NET/IIS 6 and other possible solutions is [explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005222/cant-get-servicestack-to-work-in-iis6-with-https/10005741#10005741).